# Python, comparar dos archivos

Tags: python, python-2.7, if

Tengo que leer todos los archivos que hay dentro de un directorio y luego compararlos con los de un archivo .txt

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile,join

mi_path = "c://python27//proyectos//"
f = open(mi_path+'datos.txt', 'r+')
b = open(mi_path+'nuevo_dato.txt', 'w+')

datos = f.read()


for(ruta, directorio, archivos) in os.walk(mi_path):
      for i in archivos:
            b.write(i)

      print "Directorio leido"      
      nuevoreg = b.read()

      if datos == nuevoreg:
                        print "NO hay un fichero nuevo"
      else:
                        print "SI hay un fichero nuevo"


f.close()
b.close()
```

El problema es que cuando guardo la lista que obtengo de leer el directorio en el .txt nuevo_dato, este se guarda con un montón de codificación a mayores de los archivos que hay en el propio directorio.

> 1.txt2.txt3.txt4.txtdatos.txtdoc 2.txt
>
> > ```
> >                          j                             t
> > ```
> >
> > j   &                          f                             } 
> >                               t   '               ç         t
> >        _                             t   '

Al hacer la comparación entre datos.txt y nuevo_dato.txt siempre me dice que hay datos nuevos por que se almacenan todos esos datos en el txt.
Si hago un print i para monstrar la lista de datos del directorio antes de grabarlos en el txt funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando los graba.

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal? y otra pregunta,  ¿ Se podría almacenar los archivos que contiene el directorio en una lista en vez de un txt ?

Buenas @FJSevilla , si exacto, lo que quiero es leer los archivos que hay dentro del directorio y comprarlos con los nombres que hay dentro de datos.txt y que cuando al hacer os.walk haya uno nuevo me avise. Dentro de datos.txt pongamos que tengo: doc1.txt doc2.txt doc3.txt que son los mismos archivos que tengo dentro del directorio. El problema como comento es que al hacer el write en el archivo nuevo_dato para volcar el retorno de os.walk me añade un montón de cosas ademas del nombre de los archivos, pero si hago un print para mostrar el resultado de os.walk en el interprete, esos caracteres no aparecen por ningun lado y me da imprime por pantalla los nombres de los archivos que hay dentro del directorio por orden alfabético.No se cual es el motivo por el cual, si hago print me muestra la lista bien pero si hago un write al .txt para luego comprar ambos falla.

Comment: Devp por aclarar un poco la pregunta, ¿lo que intentas es leer los **nombres** de los arhivos del directorio y compararlos con los nombres guardados en datos.txt? Es decir, solo buscas si hay algún archivo nuevo o renombrado, no comparas el **contenido** de estos. Si es así, cual es el contenido exacto de datos.txt (que estructura tiene), lo digo porque la comparación que haces no te va a servir ya que `os.walk` no tiene porqué retornar siempre en el mismo orden los archivos, por lo que comparar dos cadenas `datos == nuevoreg` no es útil si no se ordena o se usa otro método de comparación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes se debe a que estas leyendo después de escribir sin descargar el buffer (ni cierras ni fuerzas el volcado manualmente) y sin volver a colocar el puntero al principio del archivo. Para hacer lo que quieres debes hacer esto:

```
for(ruta, directorio, archivos) in os.walk(mi_path):
    for i in archivos:
        b.write(i)

b.flush() # Forzamos el volcado del buffer
m.seek(0) # Colocamos el puntero al inicio del documento.

print "Directorio leido"      
nuevoreg = b.read():
    if datos == nuevoreg:
        print "NO hay un fichero nuevo"
    else:
        print "SI hay un fichero nuevo"

f.close()
b.close()
```

No obstante, tal y como te comenté, nadie te asegura que `os.walk()` retorne en un mismo orden siempre. La opción de César es mucho más segura. Incluso se puede   usar diferencia de conjuntos en vez de listas (lo que te permite identificar además de forma eficiente cuales son los archivos diferentes) e incluso usar `pickle` para serializar directamente el conjunto con los nombres de los archivos en vez de un archivo de texto.

Answer (score 2):

Imagina que tengo contenido de el archivo `datos.txt` es:

```
$ cat datos.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
e.txt
g.txt
```

Imagina también que en la misma carpeta tengo los siguientes archivos:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:07 a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:07 b.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:07 c.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar 31 Jul 13 09:07 datos.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:08 d.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:08 e.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:08 f.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  4 Jul 13 09:08 g.txt
```

Por lo tanto, a simple vista, podemos decir que dentro de `datos.txt` solo faltan los archivos `d.txt` y `f.txt`. Si lo que quieres es saber qué archivos en el directorio no están contenidos en `datos.txt` puedes hacer:

```
>>> a = open('datos.txt')
>>> datos = a.read().split()
>>> print datos
['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'e.txt', 'g.txt']
>>> import os
>>> nuevos_archivos = []
>>> mi_path = os.path.curdir
>>> for _, _, archivos in os.walk(mi_path):
...     for archivo in archivos:
...         if archivo == 'datos.txt': 
...             continue
...         if archivo not in datos:
...             nuevos_archivos.append(archivo)
... 
>>> nuevos_archivos
['d.txt', 'f.txt']
>>> a.close()
```

Ahora que ya tienes los archivos en una lista, puedes hacer con ellos varias cosas. Si quieres agregar esos archivos faltantes a `datos.txt` puedes hacer:

```
>>> a = open('datos.txt', 'a')
>>> for archivo in nuevos_archivos:
...     a.write(archivo + '\n')
... 
>>> a.close()
```

Veamos ahora qué hay dentro del archivo:

```
$ cat datos.txt 
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
e.txt
g.txt
d.txt
f.txt
```